# How to include a variable inside <% include > in a template ejs file?

Tags: templates, ejs

I have a list of files in a folder that I need to serve inside the parent as a child template. I would like to do something like this:

```
  <% var noScriptBody = 'message-scriptless.ejs' %>
  <% include noScriptBody %>
```

or `<%include <%= noScriptBody %>/message-scriptless' %>` where `<%= noScriptBody %>` are the specific child template to include.

For example, I want to include `<% include carousel/message-scriptless %>` and `<% include modal/message-scriptless %>` where the path is variable `['carousel', 'modal', etc]`

Comment: Maybe you can see my answer, I've been updated my answer. I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can include dynamic template like this

for ex. your array passed is `pathArray` = `['carousel', 'modal', etc]`

```
<% for (const path in pathArray) { %>
   <%- include(path +'/message-scriptless.ejs') %>
<% } %>
```

Here, we iterate through the `pathArray` & include `message-scriptless.ejs` from each folder as shown in code above

Please correct me if I misunderstood your requirements

Answer (score -1):

**For an example**, you can look at this code below: `index.ejs`

```html
<!-- Only show text -->
<% var noScriptBody = 'message-scriptless' %>
<%= noScriptBody %>

<!-- Show template -->
<% var noScript = 'message-scriptless' %>
<%-  include(noScript) -%>

<!-- Show template `message-scriptless` from `carousel` directory -->
<% var carouselMessageSciptLess= 'carousel/message-scriptless' %>
<%-  include(carouselMessageSciptLess) -%>
```

> **Make sure** in the same directory, you've a file `message-scriptless.ejs`.

**Updated:** For mapping your variable, you can use this code below:

```html
<% arrayPath.forEach(function(path){ 
  include(path + '/message-scriptless');
}) %>;
```

From code above, this is an example directory structure:

- src > app.js
- views > index.ejs
- views > message-scriptless.ejs
- views > carousel > message-scriptless.ejs
- package.json

> For more information about this `ejs`, you can read this [documentation](https://ejs.co/).

**For an example**, you can look at my codeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/example-ejs-app-mhgrh

I hope it can help you.

Comment: I read this, spent a few hours reading other posts, but could not find the answer. this is why i posted this

Comment: I've been updated my answer, you can see. There's an example. You can see in my `views` directory.